# How Can we Configure Camunda Process Engine in Golang?

Tags: go, camunda

I found links on process engine Configuration
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/reference/deployment-descriptors/tags/process-engine/

But how to use this in Golang?

Answer (score 0):

You would not use the embedded process engine approach. Instead run a remote process engine and implement service tasks in Go using the external task patter. To get such a remote engine you can either just sign up for a free developer account on Camunda Cloud. If your prefer on premises, then you can use a self-managed deployment (e.g. via docker compose). For both options check here: https://camunda.com/get-started

Once you have an engine and configured credentials (follow https://docs.camunda.io/docs/guides/getting-started/).
The section https://docs.camunda.io/docs/guides/getting-started/implement-service-task/ shows how to configure the service task on the process engine side. On the Go side you can now implement an external worker (instead of zbctl in the example) as described here: https://github.com/camunda/zeebe/tree/main/clients/go